# Embedded tweet in a Mapbox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter, mapbox-gl-js

I have an issue with embedding a tweet in a popup. I'm using Mapbox GL JS and a twitter widget to style the popup content. I placed the widget in the click function like so:

```html
    // When a click event occurs on a feature in the places layer, open a popup at the
    // location of the feature, with description HTML from its properties.
    map.on('click', 'places', function (e) {
 
 //twitter widjet
 window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  t = window.twttr || {};
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
   js = d.createElement(s);
   js.id = id;
   js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

   t._e = [];
   t.ready = function(f) {
  t._e.push(f);
   };

   return t;
 }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
        
  new mapboxgl.Popup()
            .setLngLat(e.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
            .setHTML('<h3>' + e.features[0].properties.title + '</h3><p>' + e.features[0].properties.description + '</p>')
            .addTo(map);
    });
```

The tweet itself is hard-coded into the description part of a Geojson using the embed link from Twitter:

```html
map.on('load', function () {


    map.addLayer({
        "id": "places",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [{
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [-6.2285,53.3475]
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "title": "3arena",
                        "icon": "stadium",
      "description": "<blockquote class='twitter-tweet' data-lang='en'><p lang='en' dir='ltr'>.<a /*TWEET INFO*/ </a></blockquote>"
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "{icon}-15",
   "icon-size": 2,
   "icon-allow-overlap": true
        }
    });
});
```

The tweet popup works once but fails to style the popups after that even though the click function continues to work. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Here's a working example:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
   
   .mapboxgl-popup {
        max-width: 400px;
        font: 12px/20px 'Work Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiamFtZXNqaGVucnkiLCJhIjoiY2o0cHBzNjlzMmFrNjMybzR3aTZsbmNxeSJ9.GYnleaLc8niIQskdkFroLw'; // access token
    
 var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10', // style URL
   center: [-6.2285,53.3475],
   zoom: 14
    });
 
 var nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl();
    map.addControl(nav, 'top-left');

    // Add geolocate control to the map.
 map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
  positionOptions: {
   enableHighAccuracy: true
  },
  trackUserLocation: true
 }));
 
 
    
map.on('load', function () {


    map.addLayer({
        "id": "places",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [{
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [-6.2285,53.3475]
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "title": "3arena",
                        "icon": "stadium",
      "description": "<blockquote class='twitter-tweet' data-lang='en'><p lang='en' dir='ltr'>A tweet</p>&mdash; James Henry (@The_Hendawg) <a href='https://twitter.com/The_Hendawg/status/899998799728451584'>August 22, 2017</a></blockquote>"
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "{icon}-15",
   "icon-size": 2,
   "icon-allow-overlap": true
        }
    });
});

    // When a click event occurs on a feature in the places layer, open a popup at the
    // location of the feature, with description HTML from its properties.
    map.on('click', 'places', function (e) {
 
 //twitter widjet
 window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  t = window.twttr || {};
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
   js = d.createElement(s);
   js.id = id;
   js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

   t._e = [];
   t.ready = function(f) {
  t._e.push(f);
   };

   return t;
 }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
        
  new mapboxgl.Popup()
            .setLngLat(e.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
            .setHTML('<h3>' + e.features[0].properties.title + '</h3><p>' + e.features[0].properties.description + '</p>')
            .addTo(map);
    });

    // Change the cursor to a pointer when the mouse is over the places layer.
    map.on('mouseenter', 'places', function () {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });

    // Change it back to a pointer when it leaves.
    map.on('mouseleave', 'places', function () {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
    });


</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it works the first time, then fails, then probably the problem is not with Mapbox-GL-JS. Pretty hard to diagnose from your description. Can you post a live example?

Comment: Ok I've added a working example to the question.

Comment: You have? Where?

Comment: Should be there now. Stack wouldn't let me add a tweet as they had shortened urls.

Comment: I'm guessing the error at the bottom about the "places" layer not existing is part of your problem.

Comment: Hi Steve, is that error message redundant? As layer "places" does exist (it's the ID of the GeoJson) and it functions for the click event and mouse event. Plus the error seems to appear infrequently. If not, is it an issue with Mapbox GL JS?

Comment: Hey Steve I fixed the issue. It was an issue with the twitter widget. Thanks for your help.